# Can't use Chrome with wine running

Tags: wine, google-chrome, games, steam

I was running Binding of Isaac Rebirth through wine. When I went to Chrome, I tried to switch tab but nothing happened. When I closed the game and switched back to chrome, the tab had switched. I tested it with Steam and it did the same thing. When I ran another game (Cave Story+), the same thing happened but sometimes it would work without closing the game. File manager worked fine though. And I could drag the Chrome window around while running Binding of Isaac.